# Deploying to App Store using MonoTouch

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, app-store, monodevelop

I have read the documentation to allow deployment of an iOS App to the AppStore using MonoTouch.  Here is a link that explains the same:
http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/Guides/Deployment%2C_Testing%2C_and_Metrics/App_Distribution_Overview/Publishing_to_the_App_Store

I have been able to create the MonoTouch Archive using the 'Build Archive' option as explained. However, when I go to the XCode Organizer, I do not see my Archive in there. Is there a specific reason why this doesn't show up in Archive as documented?

Have any developers found any alternate means of deployment? I also saw an option called Zip App Bundle. However, I do not know if that is used anymore.

Any guidance on this issue would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think I found a way to upload using Build Zip and then Application Loader provided by Apple. However, I keep on getting invalid binary error message after the upload is successful to iTunes Connect. I am using the AppStore|iPhone Config so I don't think that is the issue. Any thoughts?

Comment: I recently did this process without problems. Do you see the archive in the monodevelop archive view (view->archives...)
Did you get any errors building the archive

Comment: @AnupMarwadi I've found you sometimes have to restart XCode for it to notice the new files there.  If you just close XCode before you start, it will work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wasn't known until recently, but the archive format that MonoDevelop outputs is only compatible with Xcode 4.5 (maybe 4.4 as well, not sure - but I know that it doesn't work with Xcode 4.2)